I cant find my address
I mean, I have my address, it's an etherium address that I used to use, but I haven't in months. I accidentally sent etherium there instead of a different address that I know. I don't know what wallet this address is or even what platform holds it. Is there any way to find out which company I should look for my wallet in?

There is no way to get it from the address, two things you can do:

go through all the platforms that you can think of have used and check.
or, if you have your mnemonics/private key backup, you can recover it back back from that.


It isn't possible to directly know what wallet service or centralize exchange your addresse comes from.
Your best bet is to:

use etherscan to check your addresses transactions and piece the puzzle

Connect to all your wallets and check what addresses it holds.

if you have private keys then use a non custodial wallet to import it and check if it's the right address


For the future I suggest you to have a trace of it. Either on a piece of paper, an encrypted file, an encrypted usb key ... in the format:
address : 0x...
key: ....

or
wallet service name: ...
addresses in use there: 0x... ; 0x....
seed phrase: ...

